# Limit duplicate queries in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I only need the latest 5 rows in my query so I use

```
$view->with('recent', Transaction::SELECT('amount')
->latest()
->where('amount', '!=', null)
->take(5)->get());
```

This gives me what I need in my view, but the DeBug Bar states:

```
14 statements were executed, 14 of which were duplicated
```

I currently have 14 records in that table. The more records I add in the table the more duplicates I get.

How can I cut down on those queries?

Currently calling it like this:

```
       @foreach($recent as $rec)
        <li>{{ number_format($rec->amount / 100, 2) }}</li>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: are you able to replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` to see the query that's being produced? Also, `->where('amount', '!=', null)` should be `->whereNotNull('amount')` I believe.

Comment: On my DD with `->toSql` I get `"recent" => "select `amount` from `transactions` where `amount` is not null order by `created_at` desc limit 5"`

Comment: seems you are putting the code block inside a loop

Comment: @kenken9999 I'm calling it this. See update in question.

Comment: where you put the code $view->with ........., it look like view composer ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm using it in a view composer so I can access it in all views. It's for my footer area.

Comment: can you try the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

change 'change.to.footer' to your footer.blade.php path

change \App\Transaction to your model path

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('change.to.footer', function ($view) {
            $view->with('recent', \App\Transaction::SELECT('amount')
                        ->latest()
                        ->where('amount', '!=', null)
                        ->take(5)->get());
        });
    }

    /**
    * Register any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

if you want use the variable in all blade,

may be you can make a model method

```
// Transaction model
public static function recent()
{
    return static::SELECT('amount')
                ->latest()
                ->where('amount', '!=', null)
                ->take(5)->get());
}
```

make a view composer

```
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('recent', \App\Transaction::recent());
    }
```

Comment: Took me a minute to wrap my head around it, but that worked like a charm after I disabled my view composer logic. Now only 1 query is being used. Thank you!

Comment: Quick question, rather than using the ViewComposer method. Can I simply add global queries to the AppServiceProvider instead?

Comment: if you want a variable can used on all blade, you can use view()->share('recent', $get_what_you_want)